# Query parameters were passed over SSL, and may contain sensitive information

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl, bundling-and-minification

I am being forced to deal with IBM AppScan results.  This one is giving me head aches. I am getting the following flag from AppScan on the following executed statement (and others just like it).

Flag: 
Query parameters were passed over SSL, and may contain sensitive information
Source:
https://.../bundles/jqueryval?v=(version)

The root of it all seems to be Bundling and Minification.

My RegisterBundles looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
...
}
```

And my _Layout.cshtml calls it like this:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>CD Renewal - @ViewBag.Title</title>
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
</head>
```

Any idea on how I can make bundling pass the version param (v) in the body as a post and not a query string?

Comment: Don't waste time figuring out POST, those must be GET requests.

Comment: "May contain sensitive information" is personally identifiable information, or data covered by PCI compliance. The version of a JS package is not sensitive information in that legal context.

Even the warning contains "may". In this situation, it does not and will never contain sensitive information, so nothing needs to be done with this for any type of regulation compliance issues.

Explain this to whoever is forcing you to deal with this, and if they try to shift blame to some auditors, speak to them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going to great lengths to talk with Microsoft Support about this, here is the abridged answer I received from them:

> "It is a by-design behavior that the query string will get added to the
>   URL as a “caching buster” so that the client doesn’t cache older
>   versions.
>
> Moreover, the query string is ignored completely at the server side
>   and it is not vulnerable to any attacks." - Microsoft Premium Support